# Filter the data with GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with data something like this

```
Id    value1    value2  IsIncluded
----------------------------------
1859    1702    4043    0
1858    1706    4045    0
1858    1703    4046    1
1860    1701    4046    0
1861    1702    4047    0
```

To get the Ids with `min(value1)` and `max(value2)` and filter based on included column I can do something like this

```
select 
    Id, min(value1), max(value2)
from table
where IsIncluded = 0
group by Id
```

and I get the result

```
Id    value1    value2  IsIncluded
-----------------------------------
1859    1702    4043    0
1858    1706    4045    0
1860    1701    4046    0
1861    1702    4047    0`
```

but can I filter the data more if there is 1 in `IsIncluded` for that Id then it shouldn't pick up that row.

Comment: Isn't that what your query with the `where` clause is doing?

Comment: Sure it is. But if there are two rows for that Id and isincluded column has values 0 and 1 in each row then it shouldn't pick up that Id. but now  it doesn't matter if there is a row with isincluded value 1 or not as long as there is a row with iscluded value 0 it picks up that ID

Comment: it's not clear what you want to happen. display or not dipslay ID that has rows with IsIncluded 1 and 0?

Comment: shouldn't display ID that has rows with IsIncluded 1 and 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Gordon Linoff, this worked for me

select Id, min(value1), max(value2)
from table
group by Id
having sum(case when IsIncluded=1 then 1 else 0 end)=0

Answer (score 2):

```
select Id, min(value1), max(value2)
from table t
where t.IsYpIncluded=0
  and not exists (
  select 0 from table t2
  where t.Id = t2.Id
  and t2.IsYpIncluded = 1
)
group by t.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this,

```
select ID,min(Value1),max(Value2) from table
where ID not in(select distinct ID from table where IsYpIncluded=1)
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking that you want to exclude any `id` that has a `1` in *any* row.  If so, you can use a `having` clause:

```
select Id, min(value1), max(value2)
from table
group by Id
having max(cast(IsYpIncluded as int)) = 0;
```

This assumes that `IsYpIncluded` is never negative, but that seems to be the case based on the data in the question.

Comment: but what if IsIncluded is a bit type. I dont think I can do a max on bit vaule

Comment: @s-a-n . . . You didn't mention that it *is* a bit type.  But it is easy enough to convert to an integer.

Comment: My bad. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Or you can use the expression `having sum(case when IsYpIncluded = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0`.

Comment: Is still returning Id with isinlcluded 0 even though it has another row for that id with isincluded 1

Comment: @s-a-n . . . These `having` expressions should filter out any `id`s that have isincluded = 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59414/discussion-between-s-a-n-and-gordon-linoff).

Comment: I should only get Ids with isIncluded value 0. But if there is another entry for an Id with IsIncluded 1 then all entries with that Id must be avoided

Comment: @s-a-n . . . Did you leave in the `where` clause?  My query doesn't have a `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

select Id, min(value1), max(value2) 
from table 
where IsYpIncluded<0 
group by Id

Comment: This would exclude my rest of the ids having with isinclude value only 0

Comment: select Id, min(value1), max(value2) from table where IsYpIncluded<= 0 group by Id

Comment: This is similar to what I have in my question. I should eliminate id with rows- isincluded value 1 and 0. but your answer will pick up Id even if there is row with value 1

Comment: Then try IsYpIncluded NOT IN(1,0) in where clause.

Comment: No my actually question is - I should only get Ids with isIncluded value 0. But if there is another entry for an Id with IsIncluded 1 then all entries with that Id must be avoided.

Comment: select Id, min(value1), max(value2) from table where IsYpIncluded= 0

Comment: Your answer will surely pickup id with isincluded 0 but doesnt exculde an Id with two rows of included 0 and 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59410/discussion-between-s-a-n-and-user3568303).